# How to progressively sum a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Forgive me if this has been asked before, I couldn't find it. I am trying to progressively sum a numpy array into a new numpy array using vector operations. What I mean by this is that the 2nd index of the new array is equal to the 1st + 2nd index of the old array. or A[n] = B[0] + B[1] ... + B[n]. I know how to do this using a for loop but I'm looking for a vectorized solution.

Here is my non-vectorized solution:

```py
import numpy as np  
A = np.arange(10)
B = np.empty(10)

for i in range(len(A)):
    B[i] = sum(A[0:i+1])

print(B)
```

Comment: it's the "cumulative sum", see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np  

A = np.arange(10)
B = np.cumsum(A)
# [ 0  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "progressive" sum is called cumulative sum. Use NumPy's [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) for this.

Using your example and comparing `B` to `np.cumsum(A)` results in equal arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.arange(10)
>>> B = np.empty(10)
>>> for i in range(len(A)):
...     B[i] = sum(A[0:i+1])
... 
>>> np.array_equal(B, np.cumsum(A))
True
```